# Started using the new Firebase website and I am getting this error while testing the Android Authentication sample program

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am not able to connect my app with my firebase database and it is giving me this error while trying to sign up or sign in.
Please help me to fix this, I have installed

Google play services : 30
Google repository
Android support repository
SDK tools 25.1.6

> 05-20 09:36:07.325 13979-13995/com.android.reactions.firebaseapp E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[dexElements=[zip file "/data/app/com.android.reactions.firebaseapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.android.reactions.firebaseapp-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Answer (score 5):

Alfonso from the Firebase team here. You can ignore the log `E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"` as a debug statement (due to a bug on play services we incorrectly log it as error) that does not explain the issue that you are having.

There may be an issue in other part of your code. Mind sharing more logs or a snippet of your code?

Answer (score 0):

have you edit proguard-rules.pro ? add this following to your proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepclassmembers class com.yourapp.**{
    *;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable **sign in ** provider in the `firebase console` , 
you can try enable Email/Password provider.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post ([Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm)) that is a Firebase bug that does not affect the behaviour of your app.