# Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"

Tags: android, firebase

So I am newbie, and I was trying to implement the Email/Password Authentication using Firebase 9.0.0
So the activity perform either the register operation or the login operation.

The login operation is running smoothly and I can see updates on the Firebase Console.
But when I try to register a new user, this error occurs,

```
E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescri ptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/deventree.com.thetimothyinitiative- 2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

My device is running Google Play services version 9.0.83.

Android Studio 2.1.1, with Google Play services SDK installed.
I have enabled sign in method in the console too.

Don't know what I'm missing!

Comment: have you seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor) ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna Yes, I tried all the given solutions.. none of them worked for me.

Comment: Can you see the registered user in the 'FireBaseConsole' ?

Comment: Just wondering how did you get your device to run Google Play Services 9.0.83? I've been trying to implement firebase as well, but running into issues on my emulator.

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi Yes, the login is working and I can see the users logged in, in the Firebase Console. It's just gives out that error with registration.

Comment: @tetuto My device already had that version installed. I understand why you're asking this, because on one of my other devices, I have an older version of Google Play Services. And can't find the update on the Play Store.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Alfonso from the Firebase team.

You can ignore the error `E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"`: unfortunately there is a bug in Play Services where this is logged as E/ rather than debug. We will deploy the fix on the next release.

This should not affect the behavior of your application, if you have an issue, look for the cause somewhere else.

Comment: Alfonso Gomez Jordana Manas. I had the same problem but I didn't install Firebase on my project but only used the previous Google Analytics Instead. This issue still appears though.

Comment: But in this resign geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 5); is not return address value it is empty array.. not find the LatLong value. Please help

Comment: Paula, could you please tell us more about your case through the [Firebase support form](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/)?

Comment: @AlfonsoGomezJordanaManas When is this update coming? You posted this answer about one month ago.

Comment: Hi Vaia. To clarify, the update just stops logging that statement, but it won't affect behavior of your app (it will just provide a better developer experience). If you have an issue, please look for the cause somewhere else :). Responding to your question, this is going out in the next version of the Google Play Services app (not SDK) after my reply, and this should be rolling out very soon (I don't have an exact date, sorry). Keep an eye out on the Play store for it.

Comment: @AlfonsoGomezJordanaManas i'm in very big problem after upgrade to last version of firebase all my work based on geofire is stopped because geofire need firebase object and firebase object not in the new sdk

Answer (score 16):

Make sure the password you're putting is not less than 6 characters! :)

Comment: I already have made sure of that condition by java methods to check validity of the password.

Comment: That doesn't seem related with the problem, I've the same problem using anonymous auth

Comment: Yes, didn't seem relevant to me too.

Comment: Well, actually this was my problem. I thought the setup was wrong, but I used a 4 chars password when tested. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Same here, @user951793

Answer (score 2):

I forget this `auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();`

It gave me same error and after adding these code helped get rid of from that error.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you do not instantiate your current user just write

FirebaseAuth.getInstance();