# Google Play service is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase and i am doing a signup activity for my app using [Official Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth#sign_in_a_user_with_an_email_address_and_password) but when i hit my signup button for register i got this error

```
Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.farrukh.firebaseaccount-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.farrukh.firebaseaccount-1/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]

W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
```

I also refer to google but due to low number of users of firebase i didn't get my answer , I also look at these both [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37328890/android-firebase-dynamitemodule-failed-to-load-module-descriptor) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm) answers but it wouldn't solve my issue.

I have google-service.json in my project i applied all dependencies what firebase project need and updated android studio.

What can i do?

**Note : Email/Password is enabled in my firebase Auth Panel**

Here's my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    private String mUserName, mUserEmail, mPassword;
    private EditText mEmail, mPass;
    Button signup;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        mPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);


        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mUserEmail = mEmail.getText().toString();
                mPassword = mPass.getText().toString();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mUserEmail,mPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });


    }// End OnCreate


}// End Activity
```

Comment: Please share your gradle build files

Answer (score 5):

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services is missing.
```

It seems that you are using a device without Google Play Service.
To test your app when using the Google Play services SDK, you must use either:

- A compatible Android device that runs Android 2.3 or higher and includes Google Play Store.
- The Android emulator with an AVD that runs the **Google APIs** platform based on Android 4.2.2 or higher.

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Answer (score 3):

Got the answer, I just uninstalled the HAXM and reinstall it solves the issue and my app successfully signup the user into my authentication panel.
However still getting this line

```
Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.farrukh.firebaseaccount-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.farrukh.firebaseaccount-1/lib/x86_64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```