# Firebase Analytics events don't show up (Android)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have an issue with Firebase Analytics. It basically boils down to the fact that nothing is registered; I have no data in my analytics page in the console.

I noticed today that when I want to send a push notification and I set a filter for the version number of my app, it shows "No versions available for this app". However, my iOS version of the app IS showing a version number in the dropdown list.

Does anyone have an idea what the issue is?

Some other issues I'm still experiencing:

- "Firebase API initialization failure." IncompatibleClassChangeError ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir() -> InvocationTargetException
- Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the failed to load is not the problem, i have it too when using firebase-invites and i found this ([Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm))

the "Firebase API initialization failure." IncompatibleClassChangeError ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir() -> InvocationTargetException 
was fixed by updating the google services in the device