# Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord using Firebase Crash services

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, android-lifecycle, crash-reports

I just added Firebase to my app with the idea of use the Crash control service and Analytics. Everything looks fine, until I close my app from Home button, and then I access to it again. After that sometimes, my app is totally Frozen, any response, any error and the only log that I can get from my logcat is:

```
01-01 15:55:40.600  1236  1262 W BroadcastQueue: Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{fb70722 u0 com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT} - receiver=android.os.BinderProxy@b6695b3, started 60009ms ago
01-01 15:55:40.600  1236  1262 W BroadcastQueue: Receiver during timeout: ResolveInfo{7bc7770 com.bq.camerabq/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver m=0x0}
01-01 15:55:40.647  1236  1262 I ActivityManager: Skipping duplicate ANR: ProcessRecord{ce79b34 8173:com.bq.camerabq/u0a96} Broadcast of Intent { act=com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT flg=0x14 cmp=com.bq.camerabq/com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver (has extras) }
```

I also have this error when I start my app for the first time, but I saw in this post that It always happend, is a Firebase common error ([Fail to read module...Firebase)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm):

```
01-01 16:18:33.155  2149  2149 D FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.
01-01 16:18:33.163  2149  2149 D FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.
01-01 16:18:33.167  2149  2186 E DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bq.camerabq-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.bq.camerabq-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.bq.camerabq-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash: com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg$zza: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzqi$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.crash.internal.zzg.zzah(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 E FirebaseCrash:     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
01-01 16:18:33.219  2149  2149 D FirebaseApp: Initialized class com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash.
```

I know that it's Firebase integration because I tried to revert my last commit with Firebase integration and this error never happened, in any device. I just added the next lines to my gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
```

and the google services plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Of course, I also added my google services file to my app. So to be honest, I don't know what is happening here. I searched a lot about this problem but I didn't find so much about it. Just a post from a guy with a similar problem than me, but for him it's happening using Cordova and Angular with Firebase, in my case is an Android app. Anyway, he didn't find a solution to [No connection on Resume Firebase+Cordova](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/firebase-angular/162x79np46/angularjs-firebase-cordova-no-connection-on-resume).

Comment: Up to now no solution, i think i should revert to GCM