# Android error with Google Play Location Services (ModuleDescriptor Class)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location, google-play-services

I am getting the following error when I am trying to run my Android app with Google Maps activity.

```
E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList
```

My app already worked for a while before but I can't really define the point where the error occurred for the first time. This also happens with a new project with the standard MapsActivity from Android Studio.

Tried it with API Levels 15 and 23 on both my Sony Xperia Z3 (with API Level 23) and an AVD (with API Level 22 and 23).

I'm totally new to Android development with Android Studio and quite frustrated because I can't seem to get it to work again.

Thanks in advance,

Florian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [thread](http://www.howtodomake.com/incompatibleclasschangeerror-after-updating-to-android-build-tools-25-1-6-gcm-fcm/) that may help you about the module descriptor error. Check if you have the latest version of your Google Play service. Try to run `./gradlew -q app:dependencies --configuration compile` to help you identify what dependencies include SDK 24.x. Some libraries import the latest support library using `+` sign instead of a version. This may cause the issue by including the latest available version. Avoid `+` sign in adding dependencies.

Based also from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm),  there is a bug in Play Services where this is logged as E/ rather than debug. The fix will be deployed on the next release. This should not affect the behavior of your application and if you have an issue, look for the cause somewhere else.