# How can I wait for mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()==true in my OnMapReady method?

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I have a java class that extends the `FragmentActivity` and implements  the interfaces `OnMapReadyCallback` `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and  `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener`

I have among others this code in my  `onMapReady(GoogleMap map)` method

```
 if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

 if (mLastLocation!=null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " got last location ... mLastlocation displayed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("myPosition"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMapReady running mLastLocation == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is my implementation of my `onConnected` method

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions missing for mGoogleApiClient.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mGoogleApiClient is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
}
```

When I run this activity in my app the toast **"onMapReady running mLastLocation == null"** appears beofre the toast **"mGoogleApiClient is connected."**

How can I make the content of my  if `(mLastLocation!=null) {..}` wait until `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()==true`?

I tried this:

```
if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    do{Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mGoogleApiClient getting last location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();} while (mLastLocation==null);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " got last location ... mLastlocation displayed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("myPosition"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
```

and `wait(2000); //wait 2 seconds` like this:

```
if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    try {
        wait(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " got last location ... mLastlocation displayed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("myPosition"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
```

although I don't think this would be a nice final implementation just to see my current location on the map.

I got a black screen instead of my map in the first case and saw my map loading for a short time in the second case then landed in an other activity of my app.

I also tried this and got a block screen instead of my map:

```
    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    do{
        int waiting =0;
        if (waiting <1000){waiting++;} else{waiting =0;}} while (mLastLocation==null);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " got last location ... mLastlocation displayed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("myPosition"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
```

I would be thankful for any hints or help.

@itsBGO:

```
package com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class NeueRouteAufzeichnen extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location mLastLocation;
private Location previousLocation;
private long distanceTraveled;

private boolean tracking = false;
private long startTime;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
private boolean gpsFix;

private static final double MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR = 100 * 60 * 60;
private static final double MILES_PER_KILOMETER = 0.621371192;
private static final int MAP_ZOOM = 18;

private List<Location> locations;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
LocationListener mlocationListener;
GoogleMap map;
LatLng myPosition;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_neue_route_aufzeichnen);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locations = new ArrayList<Location>();


}

protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "NeueRouteAufzeichnen Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mGoogleApiClient, viewAction);
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "NeueRouteAufzeichnen Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mGoogleApiClient, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions missing for mGoogleApiClient.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mGoogleApiClient is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(mLastLocation!=null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES! mLastLocation!=null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    locations.add(mLastLocation);

    if(map!=null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " got last location ... mLastlocation displayed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("newPosition"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
        draw();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection of mGoogleApiClient is suspended.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void addPoint(Location location) {
    locations.add(location);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "addPoint has been called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    distanceTraveled = 0;

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMapReady is called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            float LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 5000;
            long LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 0;

            mlocationListener = new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    updateLocation(location);
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                }
            };

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mlocationListener);
        }

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "NO Sleep");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        if (mLastLocation != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
            LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("newPosition"));
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
            draw();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMapReady running BUT mLastLocation == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


        tracking = true;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " mGoogleApiClient.connect()call from onMapReady!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));




}


protected void updateLocation(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "updateLocation method called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (location != null && gpsFix == true) {
        addPoint(location);

        if (previousLocation != null)
            distanceTraveled += location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
    }

    previousLocation = location;
}

public void draw() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Draw method called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (map == null) {
        return;
    }

    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();

    options.color(Color.parseColor("#CC0000FF"));
    options.width(5);
    options.visible(true);

    for (Location locRecorded : locations) {
        options.add(new LatLng(locRecorded.getLatitude(),
                locRecorded.getLongitude()));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "draw method got new location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng newPosition = new LatLng(locRecorded.getLatitude(), locRecorded.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newPosition).title("newPosition"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newPosition));

    }

    map.addPolyline(options);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection of mGoogleApiClient failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}
```

**@Louis Grignon:** It's a live route tracking activity in my app. I added checking for map!=null and the following version of my code has no errors but shows no marker on the map.

```
package com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class NeueRouteAufzeichnen extends FragmentActivity implements    OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location mLastLocation;
private Location previousLocation;
private long distanceTraveled;

private boolean tracking = false;
private long startTime;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;
private boolean gpsFix;

private static final double MILLISECONDS_PER_HOUR = 100 * 60 * 60;
private static final double MILES_PER_KILOMETER = 0.621371192;
private static final int MAP_ZOOM = 18;

private List<Location> locations;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

GoogleMap map;
LatLng myPosition;
boolean mapIsReady = false;

com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener mlocationListener = new com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        updateLocation(location);
    }

};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_neue_route_aufzeichnen);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

    }

protected void onStart() {
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    super.onStart();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "NeueRouteAufzeichnen Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(mGoogleApiClient, viewAction);
}

protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
            Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
            "NeueRouteAufzeichnen Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
            // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
            // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
            // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
            Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
            // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
            Uri.parse("android-app://com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50/http/host/path")
    );
    AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(mGoogleApiClient, viewAction);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions missing for mGoogleApiClient.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mGoogleApiClient is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
    if(mLastLocation!=null){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YES! mLastLocation!=null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    locations.add(mLastLocation);
    int waiting =0;
    if(map!=null && mapIsReady==true) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " got last location ... mLastlocation displayed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
        LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("newPosition"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
        draw();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection of mGoogleApiClient is suspended.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void addPoint(Location location) {
    locations.add(location);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "addPoint has been called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

    distanceTraveled = 0;

    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    criteria.setBearingRequired(true);
    criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
    criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_LOW);
    criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMapReady is called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            float LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 5000;
            long LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 0;
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, (LocationListener) mlocationListener);
        }

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "NO Sleep");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        tracking = true;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " mGoogleApiClient.connect()call from onMapReady!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        //map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
        mapIsReady = true;
}


protected void updateLocation(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "updateLocation method called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (location != null && gpsFix == true) {
        addPoint(location);

        if (previousLocation != null)
            distanceTraveled += location.distanceTo(previousLocation);
    }

    previousLocation = location;
}

public void draw() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Draw method called.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (map == null) {
        return;
    }

    PolylineOptions options = new PolylineOptions();

    options.color(Color.parseColor("#CC0000FF"));
    options.width(5);
    options.visible(true);

    for (Location locRecorded : locations) {
        options.add(new LatLng(locRecorded.getLatitude(),
                locRecorded.getLongitude()));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "draw method got new location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        LatLng newPosition = new LatLng(locRecorded.getLatitude(), locRecorded.getLongitude());
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newPosition).title("newPosition"));
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(newPosition));

    }

    map.addPolyline(options);

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection of mGoogleApiClient failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

and here is my xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/map"
tools:context=".NeueRouteAufzeichnen"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

I get the following red log when running (clean and rerun)

> didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.moduledescriptor"

First I thought it is an error until I read [this thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm).

The problem is also that the content of my `if(map!=null && mapIsReady==true) {...}` is never called.

this is the complete red log message I get

> /DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find
>   class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates.ModuleDescriptor"
>   on path: DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.noureddine_ouertani.www.wocelli50-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64,
>   /system/lib64]]

Comment: can you add your method of how you getting mLastLocation ? And i will help you !

Comment: It's there. see my `onConnected`  method.

Comment: You do not see any error in your android console which could result in a crash? Sorry, had to ask :)

Comment: see @Louis Grignon

Answer (score 0):

You're checking for mLastLocation in the onMapReady method while mGoogleApiClient is still connecting.

Have your class implement LocationListener and override onLocationChanged instead of creating an anonymous LocationListener inside onMapReady.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    updateLocation(location);
}
```

Place the following code inside the onConnected method instead of onMapReady. Also call the requestLocationUpdates method inside the else block that runs if your mLastLocation==null.

```
if (mLastLocation!=null) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " got last location ... mLastlocation displayed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("myPosition"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMapReady running mLastLocation == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mlocationListener);
    }
```

Place the following code inside your onLocationChanged or updateLocation method.

```
if (mLastLocation != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
    LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("newPosition"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
    draw();
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMapReady running BUT mLastLocation == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: It didn´t work. An empty (a loading?) Google Map is displayed for a short time then the activity ends. I'm trying to understand why...

Comment: Was any error or stack trace provided when the activity ends?

Comment: yes map was null. When I add a check for map!=null I see a map no errors BUT no marker on the map for my position although I verified that mLastLocation is not null. I'll post my current version of the whole class here so that you can have a look at it. It's a route live tracking activity.

Comment: It's a timing issue. I need to somehow synchronize my `OnMapReady` and `Onconnected`

Comment: see @BGO in the original post

Comment: I updated my answer, continue checking for map!=null and when the location changes it will update because you implemented LocationListener instead of instantiating it as an anonymous class withing onMapReady

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the following call: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME, LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE, mLocationListener)` needs an object (an instance) of type LocationListener and when I make my class additionally implement the interface LocationListener and add the needed Overrides (I tried it)  the wohle class becomes able to act like a LocationListener but conains no object of type LocationListener anymore and the call above makes no sense anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you extract your code in a separate method, an call it after onConnected, like the following example:

**Your onMapReady code**

```
 if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
   mGoogleApiClient.connect();
 } else {
   initMapLocation();     
 }
```

**Your onConnected code**

```
 @Override
 public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)      {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permissions missing for mGoogleApiClient.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "mGoogleApiClient is connected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     mLastLocation =     LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
   initMapLocation(); 
 }
```

**Your initMapLocation code**

```
 private void initMapLocation() {
   if (mLastLocation!=null) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " got last location ... mLastlocation displayed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         LatLng myPosition = new LatLng(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude());
         map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("myPosition"));
         map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(myPosition));
     }else {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onMapReady running mLastLocation == null", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

Anyway, don't use fixed duration waits (because they remain unpredictible), even less active waits (because they use the processor intensively).

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It´s the same idea as itsBGO. (see his answer). It doesn´t work. An empty (a loading?) Google Map is displayed for a short time then the activity ends. I'm trying to understand why...