# Firebase token not getting generated. FirebaseInstanceIdService is not starting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

There is the following error:

> Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"

I am using 
firebase 9.0.0

I have tried with different version of firebase versions.
I have cleaned and disabled instant run.

Comment: According to the Firebase team, this is a bug that you can ignore: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37424584/5280641. Your problem may be not related to this error log.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm)