# Android - Firebase authentication giving error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am developing an android application with Firebase and I want to use the email/password authentication that Firebase provides.

But I keep getting following error:

```
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

I have searched around, but I can't fix the problem.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37370258/failed-to-load-module-descriptor-class-didnt-find-class-com-google-android-gm

Comment: sounds like a Google Play Services version issue

Comment: update your question with build.gradle file may be we can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app/build.gradle include these new dependencies:

```
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.0'
```

and check in SDK tools Google Play Service and Google Repository asking for update, if yes then Update to latest version